# In the given figure, $AB=AC$. Prove that

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $AB=AC$. Prove that $PQ+PS=BR$[image]

My Attempt :

Since $AB=AC$, it's an isosceles triangle

Also,

$Ar (\triangle ABC)=\frac {1}{2} AC.BR$

Now what should I do next?

Comment: What are the points $P,Q,R,S$ ? I suppose $R$ is the projection of $B$ onto $AC$ but could you specify?

Comment: The points Q, R and S are the point of perpendicular

Comment: hint: area of the whole triangle is the sum of the areas of $APC$ and $APB$

Comment: It means AP is to be joined?

Comment: Yes, can you work that out?

Comment: OK, then I can do it now

Comment: It may be helpful if next time you draw the picture as precise as possible. In your sketch, $AB$ doesn't look equal to $AC$, the right angles don't look "right" :-).

Answer (score 1):

Reflect points $A$ and $S$ along line $BC$. Let $A'$ be the image of $A$, let $S'$ be the image of $S$.

$ABA'C$ is a rhombus, hence a parallelogram. The distance between opposite sides $BA'$ and $CA$ is constant, so

$$BR = S'Q = S'P + PQ = SP+PQ$$